# Double Entry Accounting System, report generation issue. DO we need summation of all journal entries always?

Tags: django, postgresql, database-design, accounting

I am working on an accounting solution, where the db has these relevant columns:

```
1. Account (The chart-of-account column)
2. Journal (This is one row for each journal entry)
3. Journal Line Item (Now, one journal entry can have more than 2 
entries, hence this 3rd table, with a FK to 2nd table). This table has 
an FK to Table 1 as well
```

Now, let's say we need to generate Trail Balance in the month of January (assuming an accounting year is from 1st Apr to 31st Mar). As of now, I'm having to do a complete summation of all the journal entries, account wise to come up with a report. 
This holds true for all other reports. Is there a better DB design/way to do it?

P.S.: One way is to maintain the Account balance as on date in Table 1. However, let's say the user needs the Trial Balance of previous month/quarter? This results in the solution being in soup again.

Note: We are using Django, Postgresql.

Comment: This question is a perfect fit for the Accounting site (currently a proposal in Area 51: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/113560/accounting?referrer=FNOG9_mXNYnhlAdnl9FE8w2 )

Answer (score 0):

Correct, a journal entry can involve 2 or more transactions. I would change the approach though. Think of it this way, there are books of prime entry (transactional log) then << journals (daily totals) then << chart of accounts (fiscal year balance). Try not to put your business logic in the database. which sounds like what you are attempting to do. the 2 or more entries is an accounting rule which in my opinion shouldn't be part of the data model.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now, with the approach you're saying, there's a problem. Let's say someone wants to update/delete a transaction committed 15 days earlier. Or let's say 100 days earlier. (While this should not happen ideally, this is allowed in most, if not all accounting software. Accounts are locked only after an accounting year). With your DB design, for edit/deletion of entry 'n' days earlier, 'n' no.of entries must change at best (n+1 at worst).